# Does the Katha Upanishad verse 2.3.1 contradict the immortality verses about Devatās?

Tags: vedas, gods, upanishads, immortality, contradiction

> ūrdhvamūlo'vākśākha eṣo'śvatthaḥ sanātanaḥ |
> tadeva śukraṃ tadbrahma tadevāmṛtamucyate |
> tasmiṃllokāḥ śritāḥ sarve tadu nātyeti kaścana | etadvaitat || 1 ||
>
> Root up and branches down is this ancient asvattha tree, that (its source) is pure. **That is Brahman and that alone is called immortal**. On that, do all worlds depend and none passes beyond that. This verily is that.[(Katha Upanishad 2.3.1)](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/katha-upanishad-shankara-bhashya/d/doc145254.html)
>
> > That which is the root of this tree of Samsâra is indeed pure, bright, i.e., resplendent, the intelligence of âtman; **that indeed is Brahman, being greater than all; that indeed is described as immortal in nature, being true; any other than that is a mere matter of speech, modification, name and falsehood and therefore subject to death**. Commentary by adi Shankara.
>
> **Another translation**
>
> “This is that eternal Ashvattha Tree with roots above
> and branches below. That indeed is the pure. That is
> Brahman. **That alone is the immortal**.
> <sup>[by SWAMI Krishnan Anda]</sup>

This verses clearly say only Brahman is immortal(or called immortal).

And commentary makes it even more clear, it only Brahman is immortal rest is subjected to death.

But it contradicts this verse :

> When mortal man presents to thee **Immortal God, Agni**, his fuel or his sacrificial gift, Then thou art his Adhvaryu, Hotar, messenger, callest the Gods and orderest the sacrifice. [(Rig Veda Verse 10.91.11)](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv10091.htm)

[This](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/27181/22556) entire answer tells us that devatās are immortal.

Not just that it also contradicts the eternality of soul :

> [BG 2.20](https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/2/verse/20): The soul is neither born, nor does it ever die; nor having once existed, does it ever cease to be. The soul is without birth, eternal, **immortal**, and ageless. It is not destroyed when the body is destroyed.

**MY QUESTION : The verse from Katha Upanishad is saying that only Brahman is immortal, but the verse I have presented also say that devatās are immortal and soul is immortal. The immortality of the devatās contradicts the verse
from Katha Upanishad(2.3.1).

What is the explanation for this contradiction**.

---

One can say that the verse from Katha Upanishad is saying that Brahman is *called immortal* but still in many verses Agni is called immortal.

Comment: Atman = Brahman according to Advaita Vedanta. Gods exist separate from us as long as we dont have Jnana. This is atlest Advaitha's view. Hope my comment helps a bit

Comment: Your questions are so wonderful Bhai!

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru thanks bro 

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru you can help by upvoting it

Comment: Sorry Brother , I always forget to upvote questions, I always do for answers but forget somehow to qns! Done it !

Answer (score 1):

> **tadevāmṛtamucyate**

**tat eva amrtam ucyate**

The translator that you quoted, has translated **eva** as **alone**. The translation is fine, but there are other equally valid ways to translate it.

I would translate **eva** as **indeed**. So my translation for this sentence would be - **that indeed is immortal** or **indeed, that is immortal**.

Translated in this way, there would be no contradiction.

Comment: "That is Brahman and that **alone** is called immortal" . Or ; That is Brahman and that **indeed** is called immortal. It does not look correct.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to HSE!! Please visit [Guidelines for new users answering questions on HSE](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/125/17833). Further, kindly have a look at the [HSE HELP CENTER](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help), and then get started in here properly. Have an enriching journey ahead!

Comment: You can check the question again I have given another translation.

Comment: And I have added a commentary that makes my pint even clearer

Comment: @DarkKnight The moment you quote Shankara's commentary, you bring in the specific perspective of advaita. I did not guess that you confined yourself to the advaita perspective when you first asked this question.

Comment: @alsoran well yes, but it is just there to make my question and point clear nothing else. Not just that adi is also believed to be enlightened

Comment: @alsoran you can see the  other translation I have given

Comment: @alsoran is that you who down voted my question ; can you give reason

Comment: @DarkKnight I think a user needs at least 125 reputation to downvote. I do not have sufficient reputation to downvote.

Comment: @alsoran have you seen the another translation

Comment: @DarkKnight Please see https://sanskritdictionary.org/eva for the meanings of Sanskrit **eva**

Comment: @ I have seen it, but most of the translaters translate it as alone. I have give two translations please check it

Comment: @DarkKnight There are multiple ways of answering this question. I chose the easiest way. If you translate **eva** as alone, you need to bring in a lot more advaita vedanta to resolve the contradictions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122516/discussion-between-also-ran-and-dark-knight).

Comment: @alsoran no translater, translated it as indeed.

Comment: @DarkKnight The translators you quoted, translate **eva** in **tadeva śukraṃ** as **indeed** or leave it untranslated. But the **eva** in **tadevāmṛtamucyate** is translated as **alone**. In my opinion, translations are good, but better to read in original Sanskrit.

Comment: @alsoran how can I read the original sanskrit or understand it.  Even if yours "indeed" translation is correct. What is the difference between Brahman and agni's immortality.

Comment: @DarkKnight For learning Sanskrit, many online and offline resources are available. Please google. For your second question, it is difficult to answer in a comment.